# Manually creating ExpressionTree with multiple arguments

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm creating tree-like structure allowing user to define math operations. User choses function (say Add), and in node's leafs (at least two, but can be more) user can specify arguments (values or other functions). I thought that using Expressions is a good idea, however it seems, that Expressions supports only binary operations. I wonder if there is some way to create Add function expression with more than two arguments. For instance if I write:

```
Expression<Func<double, double, double, double>> e = (x, y, z) => x + y + z;
```

I get tree: [(x + y) + z], so clearly there is some kind of parser.

If there is nothing I could use, I will probably write some logic to manually create subtrees. Or maybe there is a better way? Any help will be appreciated.

Here are my simply node classes:

```
abstract class Node
{
    public abstract void PrepareExpression();
    public Expression  Expr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Node> InnerNodes { get; set; }

    protected Node()
    {
        InnerNodes = new List<Node>();
    }
}

class AddFunction : Node
{
    public AddFunction()
    {
        Name = String.Format("Sum_{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    public override void PrepareExpression()
    {
        var exprParams = new List<ParameterExpression>(InnerNodes.Count);
        foreach (var node in InnerNodes)
        {
            node.PrepareExpression();
        }
        var binaryExpression = Expression.AddChecked(InnerNodes[0].Expr, InnerNodes[1].Expr);
        Expr = binaryExpression;
    }
}

class ValueArgument : Node
{
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public ValueArgument(double value)
    {
        Name = String.Format("Val_{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        Value = value;
    }

    public override void PrepareExpression()
    {
        var constantExpression = Expression.Constant(Value, typeof(double));
        Expr = constantExpression;
    }
}
```

And for evaluating whole tree:

```
rootNode.PrepareExpression();
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<double>>(rootNode.Expr);
var exprCom = expr.Compile();
var result = exprCom.Invoke();
```

Comment: "so clearly there is some kind of parser" - well there's a parser in the C# compiler, and there's a *formatter* which will convert the expression tree to a string... it's not clear what parser you're talking about here though. There simply isn't an addition operator with more than 2 operands.

Answer (score 2):

The expressions in your example are binary and that's all you need. Just apply them multiple times. The example you provided yourself:

```
x + y + z = (x + y) + z
```

corresponds to two applications of a binary operator, i.e. two binary expressions:

```
Add( Add(x, y), z)
```

There are two key observations here:

- the result of applying `Add` is itself an expression, so it can be the operand of yet another `Add` operation
- there is no such thing as a ternary add operation: "1 + 2 + 3". The latter is just shorthand for (1 + 2) + 3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to parse strings into expressions?  If so, don't reinvent the wheel.  Check out Dijkstra's [Shunting Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).